# Magento 2 This site can’t be reached ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: magento2

My website creativehands.in built on Digital Ocean server is not opening with the error, "This site can’t be reached ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ". We are using Magento 2.1.5. How to fix this? It happened automatically.

Also, I inserted an iframe in one of the pages of a link without SSL(http). Is this might be the reason for this error? (The site was working fine for almost 10 - 12 days even after I inserted the iframe part).

Also, My disk space on Digital Ocean has very less free space(only about 1 - 2 GB free). Is this less free disk space the cause? Because, I have been searching alot of forums and they mention that the Magento SQL requires a good amount of free disk space to function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can Follow this Link :-

https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-404-error-page-not-found-admin-url-magento-2/

Hope it will help you...!

If It Works for you than please mark it GREEN. Thanks